# Simple excel forms and table

Tags: python, pandas, pysimplegui

I am working on a form to input data and want to link it to a table
I have at least gotten to a point such as this but really cannot go any further
I am sure this is simple but if someone could assist me that would be great

I am trying to get the input from the form to actually input correctly to the table so that the information can easily be pulled and gathered

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

# Add some color to the window
sg.theme('Darkpurple')

EXCEL_FILE = 'Childsupport.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)


layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields:')],
    [sg.Combo(['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'], size=(10,1))],
    [sg.Text('Select the Job:')],
    [sg.Combo(['Job 1', 'Job 2'], size=(6,1))],
    [sg.Text('What is the amount deposited:')],
    [sg.Text('Amount $', size=(8,1)), sg.InputText(key='Amount',size=(8,1)), ],

    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
    ]

window = sg.Window('Child Support Form', layout)

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key]('')
    return None


while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Submit':
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved!')
        clear_input()
        window.close()
```

[example of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O3pUR.png)

Comment: What, specifically, is your question? Please read [Why is "*Can someone help me?*" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) for background. Please take the [tour] and carefully read through the [help] to learn more about the site, including [ask], as well as [what is on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [what is not](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Please also follow the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648).

Comment: my apologies, I am trying to get the input from the form to actually input correctly to the table so that the information can easily be pulled and gathered.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pandas as pd

# Add some color to the window
sg.theme('Darkpurple')

EXCEL_FILE = 'Childsupport.xlsx'
df = pd.read_excel(EXCEL_FILE)

months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
layout = [
    [sg.Text('Please fill out the following fields:')],
    [sg.Combo(months, size=(10, 1), key='Month')],
    [sg.Text('Select the Job:')],
    [sg.Combo(['Job 1', 'Job 2'], size=(6, 1), key='Job')],
    [sg.Text('What is the amount deposited:')],
    [sg.Text('Amount $', size=(8, 1)), sg.InputText(key='Amount',size=(8, 1))],
    [sg.Submit(), sg.Button('Clear'), sg.Exit()]
]
window = sg.Window('Child Support Form', layout)

def clear_input():
    for key in values:
        window[key].update('')

while True:
    event, values = window.read()
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event == 'Exit':
        break
    if event == 'Clear':
        clear_input()
    if event == 'Submit':
        amount = values['Amount']
        try:
            amount = float(amount)
        except ValueError:
            pass
        values['Amount'] = amount
        df = df.append(values, ignore_index=True)
        print(df)
        df.to_excel(EXCEL_FILE, index=False)
        sg.popup('Data saved!')
        clear_input()

window.close()
```